# Several file extensions in VIM autocmd

Tags: vim, rubocop

I got `autocmd BufWrite *.rb :RuboCop -a` in my `~/.vimrc`

How to modify it to process `*.jbuilder` files as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can either add another file-glob, separated by `,`:

```
autocmd BufWrite *.rb,*.jbuilder :RuboCop -a
```

This is documented under `:help autocmd-patterns`. Alternatively, of course, define a separate autocmd:

```
autocmd BufWrite *.rb :RuboCop -a
autocmd BufWrite *.jbuilder :RuboCop -a
```

If all these file globs already are detected to a single *filetype* inside Vim, you can also leverage that, and define a buffer-local trigger on that:

```
autocmd FileType ruby autocmd BufWrite <buffer> RuboCop -a
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a comma:

```
autocmd BufWrite *.rb,*.jbuilder :RuboCop -a
```

For more information see `:h autocommand-pattern`.